# Unable to migrate production database with Knex on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, migration, knex.js

I am new to Knex.js and I had some issue running migration. I have an App that is running on Azure. Now, I need to migrate my production database.

I am following the knex instruction and add the flag for environment by running the following.

```
knex migrate:latest --env production
```

However, I am unable to migrate the database, it seems like I am still trying to access the local database. Part of my error code are as follow:

```
Error: connect EACCES 127.0.0.1:5432
at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)
```

I have no clue how this happen. I am running the command on Azure App Service Editor. I also attach my knexfile.js

```
    production: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: `host=${process.env.DB_HOST} port=5432 dbname=${process.env.DB_NAME} user=${process.env.DB_USER} password=${process.env.DB_PASS} sslmode=required`,
    pool: {
        min: 2,
        max: 10,
    },
    migrations: {
        directory: './db/migrations',
        tableName: 'migrations'
    },
    seeds: {
        directory: './db/seeds'
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing connection parameters as template string and it is not recognizable by the `pg` module that is used under the hood and I guess it replaces it with the default value.

Try to replace connection with the object

```
connection: {
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: 5432,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS
}
```

Not sure about the `sslmode` as I don't know whether this option exists in `knex`.